# AngularJS binding response from server not updating in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am developing a mobile application. I encountered a problem while trying to relay messages in the view that was returned from the server after an ajax call. The idea is to display the message in the view after the user clicks on a "Refresh" button.

The binding is not working exactly as I hope. It is not showing the user the current message but the one received from a previous click of the refresh button. Thus, the first time the user clicks the button after the view is loaded, nothing happens... I can't figure out why the view update is not instantaneous but rather only changes when the user clicks again.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

HTML:

```
<span ng-model="rec">{{rec}}</span>
<button ng-click="getNew()">
        Refresh
</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.rec = window.localStorage.getItem('content');
$scope.getNew = function() {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(result, textStatus, xhr) {
            ...
            window.localStorage.setItem('content', result.content);
            $scope.rec = window.localStorage.getItem('content');
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            ...
        }
    });
};
```

I know that the ajax call is successful every time since the view is updated, but one step late of when it should be. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: you can use $scope.$apply() inside success to make it work in current situation otherwise you should use $http

Comment: What @AjayBeniwal said, but I'll emphasize again that you should use $http instead of ajax.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions everyone. This indeed was the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no digest cycle after the ajax call is finished so the view does not get updated. If you use `$http` service instead of `$.ajax`. Then the view will get updated.

The code would look like this then:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('content', data);
        $scope.rec = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      ...
    });
```

Of course you must inject `$http` to your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Of course! You MUST use Angular [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service.

Read [**this**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-%24scope.%24apply%28%29) article.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do a http call, Ideally you need to create a factory for this kind of scenario. Factory which implements http will return a promise by default on which you can update your scope variable.

Syntax for factory would be:

```
myapp.factory('getHttpData',function($http){
    return{
        getData: function(){
            return $http.get('/urlA');
        }
    }
});
```

and in your controller:

```
.controller('testCtrl',['getHttpData',function(getHttpData){
       getHttpData.getData().then(function(data){
              $scope.rec = data;//Whatever you want to store in this variable
       });
  });
```